# Number of way choose ordered distinct quadruples

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I think in following manner: ∀x∈{1,2,...,n} if A included it then it must be in B∨C∨D or if x not in A it can be at any B∨C∨D such a way give us 7n .Any one can verify my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Numerator is $e^{\frac 1 n \ln (999)}-1$. And $\frac {e^{x}-1}x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. Compare with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{1+\alpha}}$.

Comment: Compare the given series with the series $\sum \frac1  {n^{1+\alpha}}$. Show that the ratio of the general terms of these series converges to a positive number. So the given series converges if and only if the new one conveges, which is true for all $\alpha >0$. @AlexAdams

Comment: @AlexAdams The sreies does not converge for $\alpha =0$ (by comparison with the harmonic series).